# Anybody can create tags on newly created beta sites?

Tags: discussion

Just created this question in our wonderful beta.

What really surprised me - I created some initial tags, and they was created without any trouble. Although I have only a simple user with minimal reputation.

Does it work always so?

Comment: Welcome to being in Beta.  :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Private beta sites have much more lax restrictions on new users, well, because we're all new users here. This is done so we can self-moderate early on.

Once we reach public beta the standards get more strict, and even more so after full launch.

You can check any site's privileges by viewing the [/privileges](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page.

Comment: Yes, this is how we "bootstrap" a community where users do not yet have the reputation needed to add these essentials.